# C# How to fire routine by Quartz.net every day at specific time of day

Tags: c#, quartz.net

i am not before dev pc but i got a code which seems like work.

```
private void QuartzTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // construct a scheduler factory
    ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();

    // get a scheduler
    IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
    sched.Start();

    IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<LoggingJob>()
        .WithIdentity("myJob", "group1")
        .Build();

    ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
       .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
         (s =>
            s.WithIntervalInHours(24)
           .OnEveryDay()
           .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(08, 00))
         )
       .Build();

    sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
}
```

it seems the trigger will trigger job every day at 8:00 AM every morning.
anyone can confirm that really does the above code will trigger my routine every day at 8:00 AM every morning ?

i asked this kind of question because i am not before dev pc so i can not test the above code that it will work fine or not?

also i am curious to know how could i exclude Saturday and Sunday as a result my routine will not be fire. where to add day name no to fire my routine. only my routine should be fire from Monday to Friday.

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do it only on weekdays you can use a cron expression like this

```
0 0 8 ? * MON-FRI *
```

Usage is described [here](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/crontriggers.html)

Would look like this for you

```
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
       .WithCronSchedule("0 0 8 ? * MON-FRI *")
       .Build();
```

This should fire every day at 8am except for weekend

You can use this website to generate your cron expressions: http://www.cronmaker.com/

Comment: I updated answer as I initially used the unix cron format and Quartz seems to use slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it on weekdays without using a cron expression, you can also use:

```
    var trigger = TriggerBuilder
                 .Create()
                 .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder
                                  .AtHourAndMinuteOnGivenDaysOfWeek(8,
                                                                    0,
                                                                    DayOfWeek.Monday,
                                                                    DayOfWeek.Tuesday,
                                                                    DayOfWeek.Wednesday,
                                                                    DayOfWeek.Thursday,
                                                                    DayOfWeek.Friday))
                 .Build();
```